# Mouse over color picker and moving object

Tags: javascript, user-interface, colors

I have a color picker that appears only when i click on another gui texture button. also i have an object that has a rotating script behind it. how can i tell the object to not rotate when i am using the color picker ?

This is the rotating script.

```
function LateUpdate () {   
if (isCameraInputIgnored() ) {
        return;
}   

if (target && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
    x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02;
    y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02;

    y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

   var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

    var position = rotation * Vector3(0.0, 10.0, -distance) + target.position;

    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
}
}
```

This function returns true if the mouse is over the 2 always present guitextures.

```
function isCameraInputIgnored () : boolean {
var mousePos : Vector3  = Input.mousePosition; 
// invert the y-coordinate 
mousePos.y = Screen.height - mousePos.y;
if ( tilesBlock.Contains(mousePos) || wallBlock.Contains(mousePos)) 
    return true;


return false; //if mouse isn't over gui's
}
Declaration :
private var tilesBlock : Rect = Rect(0,0,570,182) ; //tiles rectangle
private var wallBlock : Rect = Rect(670,0,590,172) ; //walls rectangle
```

In the LateUpdate functon i use this code to not rotate my object :

```
if (isCameraInputIgnored() ) {
        return;
}
```

My problem is that after one of the second gui texture buttons is pressed a color picker appear that is declares like a GuiLayout.BeginArea(Rect) and when i drag my mouse through color my house is movng and changing colors at the same time. I want my house fixed when i am using the color picker.

Comment: Add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) code here, to help others to help you.

Comment: i hope that someone will understand my problem and post  a solution. thanks in advanced.